# Pause MySQL indexing while importing from CSV or EXCEL file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, indexing

how can I stop mysql indexing while importing data to my database. I have a Rails Application where users can import data from file. I adds some indexes to get faster
results searching for phone numbers and email adresses.

My contact model has some more relations to other models that I strip out for an easier example:

```
  create_table "contacts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "status"
    t.integer  "gender",                :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.string   "salutation",                               :null => false
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "first_name",                               :null => false
    t.string   "last_name",                                :null => false
    t.binary   "phone"
    t.binary   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               :null => false
    :
    :
  end

  add_index "contacts", ["phone"], :name => "index_contacts_on_phone"
  add_index "contacts", ["email"], :name => "index_contacts_on_email"
```

The import takes long time. Can I prevent MySQL to build up the indexes while importing thousand of contacts? After import I will enable the index. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do both those tasks concurrently. 
Have you heard of sidekiq? which runs the process you want in background. So the mysql indexing in the background. You have to create a process worker for the indexing, so it won't interrupt your importing of files.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Just go through their basics and you will get the gist of it.

Comment: I using sidekiq for the import. The users should load there files up to the server and starting the import process. Sidekiq imports all the data. But the process is slow and the load on the database (server) is very high. My idea was stopping in the sidekiq worker process the indexing when an import will start and starting and reindex it, when the import is finished.

Comment: In the worker which you are importing the data,create some temporary variables/objects which hold the data, only save those to the database every when a certain no of them are created . It will reduce the database load.